# Is there a term for non-multipliable value?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

It seems that for some values multiplication "makes no sense", e.g.

- If something grows by 2.2% one year, 2.3% next year and 0% another year, you calculate the total growth (or start work on the geomean) by multiplying 1.022, 1.023 and 1. But multiplying 2.2, 2.3 and 0 wouldn't give any meaningful number.
- If the air in a balloon is at 20°C temperature and some process doubles the gas temperature, you can't get the result by multiplying the 20 by 2. You have to convert to absolute temperatures (e.g. Kelvins) first.

Is there a common term for this "multipliability" property?

Comment: You can speak of a *multiplicative* constant, and that will be understood (as a number used as a factor). But a *non-multiplicative* constant would not.

Comment: This feels related to, but not perfectly the same as, the linear algebra concepts like "You can't add times/positions in space together. But you can add durations/displacements to each other or to times/positions."

Comment: Almost @MarkS. but you can actually add the absolute times/positions to find their averages, e.g. finding the geometric center of a body involves adding positions as a legitimate step. But I can't think of anything where multiplying degrees Celsius would be "correct".